# Put text on Windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is it possible to put some text on Windows 8 desktop without adding text on background image? Can I write something to text file and then ask windows to show it's content on desktop? How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Bginfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bginfo.aspx) would *modify* the background image, but would totally do it. While by default, it shows a range of useful information, you can set an arbitary bit of text. Works from anything from XP to 10. Its portable (you run it and it creates the background image).

For what *you* want - you need a user defined field pointing at a text file. Annoyingly, if you do this, it will *always* show the identifier.

You can also do just plain text.

Here's an example of using a custom field called words, how it would look like and your various options

[image]

Answer (score -2):

No. Personalization of background for desktop id made of images. You can search for a simple image editor and add your text to an image. I don't know, but you may try to look for desktop gadgets that show quotes or post its, and this way you will have a text on desktop too.